# Passing array of objects from angular template to another component using @input

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am trying to pass an array of objects through angular template from one component to another one.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <div class="col-xl-3">
      <top-users  usersData ={{[item]}}> </top-users>
    </div>
  </div>
```

item here supposed to be

```
[{id:1, name: 'Ahmed'}, {id:2, name:'Mohammed'}]
```

and the data is array of array of objects

```
[    
 [{id:1, name: 'Ahmed'}, {id:2, name:'Mohammed'}],
 [{id:3, name: 'Ahmed'}, {id:4, name:'Mohammed'}],
 [{id:5, name: 'Ahmed'}, {id:6, name:'Mohammed'}]
]
```

When I receive the variable through @input parameter, I get the result typeof string and looks like this

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

I tried to parseJson and gives me this error

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

What should I do to get the right array of object?

Comment: I dont think `[item]` is a right way. it should be `item`. tried to keep it simple this will reduce bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the data as below :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <div class="col-xl-3">
      <top-users  [usersData]="item"> </top-users>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You will receive in child component as:

```
@Input() usersData;
```

usersData will look like:

```
[{id:1, name: 'Ahmed'}, {id:2, name:'Mohammed'}]
```

Comment: For completeness, the different flavors of Angular's template syntax are listed [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Comment: I'd also add that when you use an attribute without square brackets, you are passing a literal string and that's fine. The problem is that he was interpolating an object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I created the file with strict on, so  I modified the strict to false in `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "strict": false,
```

And also tried:

```json
 "compilerOptions": {
   "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
```

If you don't find `strict` just add it, don't forget to add comma(`,`) after `"strict": false,`. Next time create the file with `-no--strict`. ex. `ng new fileName -no--strict`